# Children of flex container nested inside another flex container not taking width well

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have one flex container, and another nested inside it. Here is [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uy5rfo), and here is code:

```
  <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <div style={{ flex: 1, border: "1px solid red" }} />
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flex: 1, border: "1px solid red" }}>
        <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>{item.label}:</div>
        <div
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            whiteSpace: "nowrap",
            overflow: "auto"
          }}
        >
          {item.value}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My goal is that children of first div container take 50/50 width.
Also, I want the children of my second flex container (the 2nd div with red border),
to take width 50/50; and I also want scrollbar for the last div if text is large.

If I use as item this object:

```
  let item = {
    label: "test ",
    value: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
  };
```

It seems to work, see here, **red divs take 50% width of screen and also there is scrollbar**. See [here](https://ibb.co/tqkp5S7)

But if I use this as item(with longer text), **now the 2nd div with red border takes too much width**:

```
  item = {
    label: "test",
    value:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ut nisi feugiat arcu elementum feugiat. Sed varius eros ac convallis interdum. Quisque tincidunt mauris vitae ipsum malesuada tempus. Cras ut dui vitae tortor finibus rhoncus ut in enim. Morbi nec nibh vitae mauris pretium convallis. Curabitur sed ornare arcu. Fusce dictum, lacus eget efficitur posuere"
  };
```

I am interested **why** this happens? and what is right fix?

---

<sub>I asked similar question some time ago but I simplified this one to make easier to answer (answer I got there didn't explain what was happening).</sub>

Comment: Just add `min-width: 0` to the nested flex container.

Comment: @gmoniava, I'm not sure what you mean. Why wouldn't it appear? The `div` has `overflow: auto` applied.

Answer (score 1):

The outer most element is a flex container, which makes the children have a min width equal to their content, thanks to `white-space: nowrap;` that min width becomes huge.

Two solutions:

1. Remove `display:flex` from the outer most element.

```html
<div>
  <div style="flex: 1 1 0;border: 1px solid red;">
    <div style=" display: flex; flex: 1 1 0; border: 1px solid red ">
      <div style="flex: 1;">test:</div>
      <div style="
            flex: 1  0;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: auto;
         ">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ut nisi feugiat arcu elementum feugiat. Sed varius eros ac convallis interdum. Quisque tincidunt mauris vitae ipsum malesuada tempus. Cras ut dui vitae tortor finibus rhoncus ut in enim.
        Morbi nec nibh vitae mauris pretium convallis. Curabitur sed ornare arcu. Fusce dictum, lacus eget efficitur posuere
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. apply `min-width:0` to it's direct child.

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="flex: 1 1 0;border: 1px solid red;min-width: 0;">
    <div style=" display: flex; flex: 1 1 0; border: 1px solid red ">
      <div style="flex: 1;">test:</div>
      <div style="
            flex: 1  0;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: auto;
         ">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ut nisi feugiat arcu elementum feugiat. Sed varius eros ac convallis interdum. Quisque tincidunt mauris vitae ipsum malesuada tempus. Cras ut dui vitae tortor finibus rhoncus ut in enim.
        Morbi nec nibh vitae mauris pretium convallis. Curabitur sed ornare arcu. Fusce dictum, lacus eget efficitur posuere
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```